# Executing BizTalk Flat file disassembler pipeline inside orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am not new to BizTalk however this situation is somewhat new. I have below situation in an BizTalk Orchestration,

1. I get path of flat file from some other source.
2. I want to load this file in orchestration and disassemble it by executing pipeline.

I searched a lot but almost every one talks about feeding a XML document in pipeline inside orchestration.

I got below links too but I couldn't get the working solution so far,

[Calling FlatFile pipeline inside orchestration](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d826e166-a274-4d27-8944-2f8ba8ba0010/calling-flatfile-pipeline-inside-orchestration?forum=biztalkgeneral)

[4 Different ways to process an XLANGMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appfabriccat/2010/06/23/4-different-ways-to-process-an-xlangmessage-within-an-helper-component-invoked-by-an-orchestration-part-1/)

When I implemented solution given at above links, I get error "*No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data.*"

I also don't want to create dynamic receive locations because of performance constrains.

Below is my code so far,

1. Load file content in a stream
2. Create a CustomBTXMessage instance as suggested in link two.
3. Load stream as below

   customBTXMessage = new CustomBTXMessage("MyMessageName",

   Service.RootService.XlangStore.OwningContext);
                       customBTXMessage.AddPart(string.Empty, "Body");

   customBTXMessage[0].LoadFrom(ms);

   return customBTXMessage.GetMessageWrapperForUserCode();

I think this situation is not something new in BizTalk world. Any one who has done this must be able to help me quickly.

Comment: A) Why can't you use the File Adapter to read the file?  B) Do you have to process the file in the same Orchestration where you discover the path?

Comment: So files can be in multiple folders, if think to start a new orchestration then I will have to create new File receive location for each path. Yes, I have to process the file in same orchestration.

Comment: Is there a correlation you can use between the flat file (contents or filename) and the flow you are in?

Comment: So...why can't you create multiple Receive Locations?  There's no problem with that.  Then, following Pieter Vandenheede, is there a way to Correlate the files?  There would have to be a shared value.

Comment: so the situation is that I get a list of file paths from a source and then have to process those flat files sequentially. two files can not be process at same time. One solution could be to download all files in first orchestration and then create another orch having correlation over receive port name. In this case I will have to create multiple receive locations in side one receive port. But issue with creating two orch is that I will have to go out of BizTalk and then initiate or read all other variables that I already have in first orch.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do...or at least try first.

1. Create a Receive Port and Receive Location for each Flat File type you get.
2. Get the list of files.
3. In the Orchestration, Move the file to the appropriate Receive Location.
4. Flat File Disassembler the file in Port Pipeline like normal.
5. Receive the File into the Orchestration with an Ordered Delivery Port bound to the Receive Port from Step 1.
6. Loop on Receiving the files, checking for BTS.LastInterchagneMessage.
7. When True, Exit that Loop and go back to step 3.

Comment: thanks Johns, I would go with this approach in case I wont get a solution by tomorrow.

Comment: @Prasoon Solution too...?  For clarity, I would avoid reading the file in the Orchestration, though that is possible.  It's just more complicated and less of the 'BizTalk Way'.